# how to set background color in the xml layout?

Tags: java, android

I couldn't find information on how to do this anywhere? I want to define a background color in the xml layout of the activity. How do I do this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Take your outer layout (e.g. a `LinearLayout`) and set its background attribute to a color.

```
<LinearLayout android:background="@color/mycolor"
              .... />
```

These colors can be defined in the `res/values/colors.xml` file *(see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color) how to do this)*.

You can also define a color directly at the attribute (`android:background="#ffff0000"`), but that's usually not good. By defining the colors in the XML file you can give it a descriptive name *(improves code readability)* and you can reuse it somewhere else.

---

**Edit:**
Theres an example in the doc I linked, but here is a short example how it looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#ffff0000</color>
    <color name="green">#ff00ff00</color>
</resources>
```

Its basically a `resources` tag containing multiple `color` tags. Each color has a `name` attribute (which you use to reference the color) and an actual color. That is defined between the color tags in hex. See the docs for possible formats. This one is `#AARRGGBB`, where `A=alpha` *(transparency)*, `R=red`, `G=green` and `B=blue`. This example file contains a full red and a full green color. They can be referenced via `@color/red` and `@color/green`.

Comment: can you show me how to set up a colors.xml file? i created a new xml file but how do i set the color values?

Comment: Edited a short explanation. :)

Answer (score 3):

there is one thing need to mention is that the `"android:background="#ffffffff""` setting does not work if this sentence is applied to an include directive.

for example,

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/fragment_printer_detail_property_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/printer_detail_group_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/printer_detail_group_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/printer_detail_group_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/printer_detail_group_vertical_margin"
    layout="@layout/module_printer_detail_property"
    android:background="@color/module_printer_detail_group_background_color" />
```

the `"android:background"` should be set in the layout file of module_printer_detail_property.